# Calculate count of a numeric column into new columns Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
  Movie Rate
0 5821  4
1 2124  2
2 7582  1
3 3029  5
4 17479 1
```

both movie and the rating could be repeated. I need to transform this DataFrame to something like this:

```
  Movie Rate_1_Count Rate_2_Count ... Rate_5_Count
0 5821  20           1                5
1 2124  2            0                99
2 7582  50           22               22
...
```

which the movie ids are unique and Rate {Number} Count is the count of the ratings to that movie that are equal to the {Number}.
I already accomplished this task using the code below which I believe is very messy. I guess there must be a neater way to do that. Can anyone help me with it?

```
self.movie_df_tmp = self.rating_df[['MovieId', 'Rate']]

self.movie_df_tmp['RaCount'] = self.movie_df_tmp.groupby(['MovieId'])['Rate'].transform('count')
self.movie_df_tmp['Sum'] = self.movie_df_tmp.groupby(['MovieId'])['Rate'].transform('sum')
self.movie_df_tmp['NORC'] = self.movie_df_tmp.groupby(['MovieId', 'Rate'])['Rate'].transform('count')

self.movie_df_tmp = self.movie_df_tmp.drop_duplicates()
self.movie_df_tmp['Rate1C'] = self.movie_df_tmp[self.movie_df_tmp['Rate'] == 1]['NORC']
self.movie_df_tmp['Rate2C'] = self.movie_df_tmp[self.movie_df_tmp['Rate'] == 2]['NORC']
self.movie_df_tmp['Rate3C'] = self.movie_df_tmp[self.movie_df_tmp['Rate'] == 3]['NORC']
self.movie_df_tmp['Rate4C'] = self.movie_df_tmp[self.movie_df_tmp['Rate'] == 4]['NORC']
self.movie_df_tmp['Rate5C'] = self.movie_df_tmp[self.movie_df_tmp['Rate'] == 5]['NORC']
self.movie_df_tmp = self.movie_df_tmp.replace(np.nan, 0)
self.movie_df = self.movie_df_tmp[['MovieId', 'RaCount', 'Sum']].drop_duplicates()
self.movie_df_tmp = self.movie_df_tmp.drop(columns=['Rate', 'NORC', 'Sum', 'RaCount'])
self.movie_df_tmp = self.movie_df_tmp.groupby(['MovieId'])["Rate1C", "Rate2C", "Rate3C", "Rate4C", "Rate5C"].apply(
lambda x: x.astype(int).sum())
self.movie_df = self.movie_df.merge(self.movie_df_tmp, left_on='MovieId', right_on='MovieId')
self.movie_df = pd.DataFrame(self.movie_df.values,
columns=['MovieId', 'Rate1C', 'Rate2C', 'Rate3C', 'Rate4C',
'Rate5C'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab):

```
pd.crosstab(df['Movie'], df['Rate'])
```

```
Rate   1  2  4  5
Movie            
2124   0  1  0  0
3029   0  0  0  1
5821   0  0  1  0
7582   1  0  0  0
17479  1  0  0  0
```

---

Fix axis names and column names [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#pandas-dataframe-rename) + [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas-dataframe-reset-index) + [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html#pandas-dataframe-rename-axis):

```
new_df = (
    pd.crosstab(df['Movie'], df['Rate'])
        .rename(columns=lambda c: f'Rate_{c}_Count')
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

```
   Movie  Rate_1_Count  Rate_2_Count  Rate_4_Count  Rate_5_Count
0   2124             0             1             0             0
1   3029             0             0             0             1
2   5821             0             0             1             0
3   7582             1             0             0             0
4  17479             1             0             0             0
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the desired output:

```
grouper=df.groupby(['Movie','Rate']).size()
dg=pd.DataFrame()
dg['Movie']=df['Movie'].unique()
for i in [1,2,3,4,5]:
  dg['Rate_'+str(i)+'Count']=dg['Movie'].apply(lambda x: grouper[x,i] if (x,i) 
  in grouper.index else 0)
```